# Matlab - how to catch warning released by cp2tform function

Tags: matlab, error-handling, warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a set of `N` sets of 2D points and I want to parse these `N` sets in order to find the affine transformation(translation, rotation, scaling including reflexion) with another set `q` of 2D points.

In order to do so, I am applying the Matlab function `cp2tform`. However, there are certain scenarios when the function gives me a warning similar to the one illustrated bellow:

```
Warning: The condition number of A is 117632159740.8394. 
> In maketform>validate_matrix at 328
  In maketform>affine at 163
  In maketform at 129
  In cp2tform>findAffineTransform at 265
  In cp2tform at 168
```

In these cases, the transformation matrix identified with the `cp2tform` function does not apply to the real transformation between the 2 sets of 2D points. How can I catch these situations in order to skip them? What matlab function or code should I introduce in order to catch these situations in order to be able to skip or handle them?

Comment: see this: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently

Comment: Note that the [doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/cp2tform.html) states: `cp2tform` is not recommended. Use `fitgeotrans` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Handle Warning:

As explained [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently), you could convert specific warnings to errors, and trap those inside a try/catch block.

Here is an example on how to handle a specific warning (inverting a nearly singular matrix):

```
% turn this specific warning into an error
s = warning('error', 'MATLAB:nearlySingularMatrix'); %#ok<CTPCT>

% invoke code trapping errors
try
    A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
    B = inv(A);
    disp(B)
catch ME
    if strcmp(ME.identifier, 'MATLAB:nearlySingularMatrix')
        fprintf('Warning trapped: %s\n', ME.message);
    else
        rethrow(ME);
    end
end

% restore warning state
warning(s);
```

---

### Suppress Warning:

Of course if you want to suppress a warning message, you could just query the last warning issued using:

```
[msgstr, msgid] = lastwarn;
```

(or use the syntax that [@Benoit_11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24450545/97160) showed), then turn it off until temporarily inside your function:

```
% turn it off
s = warning('off', msgid);

% ...

% restore state
warning(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

It might not solve entirely your problem but here is something you could try:

You can get information about warnings issued by Matlab; for instance the last warning that popped up with this line (taken from the matlab help):

```
w = warning('query','last')
```

You will get this:

```
w = 

    identifier: 'MATLAB:rmpath:DirNotFound'
         state: 'on'
```

Then you can use this very identifier to catch other instance in which matlab issues the same warning and probably skip them. I think the syntax is quite flexible. Hope that helps!